# S3 Ninja issues with remix.js

Tags: amazon-s3, remix.run

I'm working on a Remix.js app and, locally I'm using a S3Ninja container to test.

So, using the minimal viable code to make a form that uploads to S3 I have this:

```
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import { Form } from "@remix-run/react";
import { redirect } from "@remix-run/node";

export default function UploadForm() {
  return (
    <Form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </Form>
  );
}

// Configure the S3 client
const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: "us-east-1", // The region doesn't matter for S3Ninja
  endpoint: "http://localhost:9444/s3", // The address of your S3Ninja instance
  // You can provide any accessKeyId and secretAccessKey for S3Ninja
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE',
    secretAccessKey: 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
    }
});

export async function action({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const file = formData.get("file");

  if (file && file instanceof File) {
    // Convert the file stream to a Buffer
    const chunks = [];
    for await (const chunk of file.stream()) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }
    const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);

    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: "expert", 
      Key: file.name,
      Body: buffer,
      ContentType: file.type,
    });

    await s3.send(command);

    return redirect("/users/upload");
  }
}
```

when I try to upload the image I get the following error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND expert.localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
```

The point is that I'm sure that S3 Ninja is running because I can access it's UI on http://localhost:9444/ui and I can upload files on the bucket from there.

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Thanks

PS: Just to clarify some possible ideas:

1. I'm running the remix.js app from Ubuntu on WSL2
2. I don't think it's a docker network issue because I have MariaDB running from another container without errors.